# Passing Rc<RefCell<T>> back and forth between C++ and Rust

Tags: rust

According to the answer this question of mine: [How to hold Rust objects in Rust code created through C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338832/how-to-hold-rust-objects-in-rust-code-created-through-c) I can pass back to C something allocated in Rust inside a `Box`, and then receive it back again as a reference to `&T`, because Rust allocates `Sized` structs respecting the C ABI.

I want to do the same thing but now for `Rc<RefCell<T>>`. Should I return a `Box` to the `Rc<RefCell<T>>`? My guess it no since `Rc` does not implement `Sized`, which is required for `T` in `Box<T>` [according to the Box page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout). So this would not work:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_new() -> Box<Rc<RefCell<T>>> {
    Box::new(Foo { glonk: false })
}
```

How can I make this work? Basically I need to create a Rust struct that can be accessed by many, and mutably borrowed by one of these many. That's why I choose `Rc<RefCell<T>>`. Is there perhaps another type of structure that can do what I want and be C-friendly?

Comment: `Rc` _does_ implement `Sized`. How did you get to the opposite conclusion?

Comment: @E_net4theclosevoter I couldn't find `impl Sized for Rc` on Rc's page on Rust site. So I should use `Box<Rc<RefCell<T>>>`? I can't use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` simply? I couldn't find if it has the same property as `Box` (that is, its memory layout is like C layout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both smart pointers `Rc<T>` and `Box<T>` *are indeed sized types*, they implement `Sized`. This information is not presented in the documentation, probably because of the special nature of `Sized`: it is always automatically derived for all types where it's applicable, and that implementation cannot be added or lifted (unlike `Send` and `Sync`).

With that out of the way, there is little benefit in encapsulating another smart pointer into a `Box`. If there is an intention to move the actual smart pointer (`Rc`) across the C FFI boundary and back, there is only one thing to keep in mind: the layout of an `Rc<T>` is not compatible with a raw pointer, even when `T` is `Sized` ([unlike `Box<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/boxed/index.html#memory-layout)).

Therefore, we need to convert it to a raw pointer and back explicitly. The functions `into_raw` and `from_raw` are also available for `Rc`.

```
/// create a new Foo and give it to caller
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_new() -> *const RefCell<Foo> {
    Rc::into_raw(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo { glonk: false })))
}

/// clone the pointers into two
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_clone(foo: *const RefCell<Foo>) -> (*const RefCell<Foo>, *const RefCell<Foo>) {
    unsafe {
        let ptr = Rc::from_raw(foo);
        let c = Rc::clone(ptr);
        (ptr, c)
    }
}

/// get a property of a Foo without returning ownership
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_glonk(foo: *const RefCell<Foo>) -> bool {
    unsafe { (*foo).borrow().glonk }
}

/// return ownership of the Foo,
/// so it can be freed in Rust-land
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo_return(foo: *const RefCell<Foo>)  {
    let _ = Rc::from_raw(foo);
}
```